How do I set publish_time on a ROS2 mcap?
I am generating synthetic data in ROS2, and the rendering step takes longer than the sensor frame rate. This isn't a problem, or hasn't been in ROS1 - I just write the stamp I want in the message header and it's all good.
In ROS1, when I did this I could play back a rosbag with the --clock option without issue. In ROS2, I'm using mcap files for recording and playback and I just discovered there seems to be a publish_time that's part of the mcap structure.
I can't seem to find any documentation on mcap files with regards to ROS2, and I don't seem to have a way to set publish_time from the ROS2 messages.
How can I control the publish_time in the output mcap? I'm writing messages to the /clock topic and I'm also stamping my message headers with the same time, but I can't seem to affect the publish_time in the mcap.
I'm hoping for something like a --use-sim-time flag I can use with ros2 bag record, but again I can't seem to find any documentation on how this is supposed to work.


Final response:
After writing my second draft I was going to try it out and I see a ros2 bag option from ros2 bag record -h that looks like it does exactly what you want with the name you mentioned:
  --use-sim-time        Use simulation time for message timestamps by subscribing to the /clock topic. Until first /clock message is
                        received, no messages will be written to bag.


Second Draft
Rereading you post you may be doing this already at recording time. You could make sure when you're generating the renderings that your whole system doesn't go ahead in time before the renderings are complete and lockstep the simulation. The way that you refer to it there might be a bug in the mcap recorder if it's not logging the publish_time in simulation time if sim_time is active.

Original response with a workaround and some theory.
Similarly to ivrolan's suggestion. I might suggest instead of reimplementing the recording tool. But instead write a script that will iterate the bag file and adjust the publish timestamp.
The time of publication and the timestamp are functionally different. One is when the data became available on the wire and the other is when the data was captured. As in this case the data is delivered with high latency. And when the data is recorded and then played back the latency is preserved. If this wasn't the case, you could never effectively test algorithms on recorded data, because when using recorded data the data would be available unrealistically early for the higher latency links and would reorder the data arrivals.
In this special case where you're not trying to record and reproduce a system, but are looking to generate it, and know that one simulated subsystem is unrealistically high latency, that's where I would suggest that you just reprocess the recording to shift that one subsystem's messages to make the latency accurate to the expectation of a real operational delay. Note that this is not the same as setting it to the time of header timestamp but a realistic delay after that value to account for any capture, processing and communication needed before the message is ready to go on the real camera hardware and driver.

Embarrassing, but perfect. ROS2 and mcap files are new to me. I was unaware that there were TWO stamps and thought this was something specific to mcap files, and clearly didn't do enough reading of the documentation :facepalm:  Thanks for your help!

Taking a look to the API for Python it seems that you can also write a timestamp of the moment of publishing besides the msg.header.stamp of the msg you are trying to write. Could this timestamp be the publish_time?
# note msg.header.stamp could be different to timestamp
writer.write("/chatter", serialize_message(msg), timestamp)

Instead of recording with ros2 bag record and changing the timestamp of the header of the message, you could create your own recording script that deals with this.

I can if there's no other route, but the functionality already exists to record bags/mcaps and I'd prefer to not rewrite a capture mechanism just to change one aspect of how data is recorded.
